# Rewrite wp-login.php URLS to static pages?

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling with getting a few things in WP to redirect.

I'm using a front-end profile / profile editor, and I'm also using a front-end login/register.
Naturally I would like to redirect the standard wp-login.php URLS to specific ones.

Mainly :

`http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword => http://www.mysite.com/login/forgot/`

`http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action=register => http://www.mysite.com/register/`

`http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php , http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action={anything} , etc => http://www.mysite.com/login/`

I've tried to use RewriteRule's in my .htaccess file, namely :

`RewriteRule ^login$ http://yoursite.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]`

to test out rewrites, and nothing happened.

I have also been somewhat unsuccessful with `add_rewrite_rule()`

If anyone could point me towards the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

Thanks,
Tre

Comment: Can you post more of your .htaccess file?

Comment: You can't do `http://www.mysite.com/wp-login.php?action={anything} => http://www.mysite.com/login/`, i.e. rewrite many addresses to only one. Your question lacks of precision.

Comment: Can you also post `add_rewrite_rule()` code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ozh has a great tutorial about pretty login URLs, that you might find helpful - [Pretty Login URL: a Simple Rewrite API Plugin Example](http://ozh.in/uf)